# Menu on mobile doesn't show

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my website: [here](http://www.florin-pop.com/work/Simple%20Eats/).

My menu on mobile is not showing for some reasons. I know it's hidden probably, but I can't figure it out how to fix it.

I'm using `bootstrap` framework.

Comment: It would be better if you can replicate this problem in small scale.

Comment: I can't... Just look at it with firebug or something

Comment: Actually your menu is covered by an image. So you'll to use z-index to bring it infront.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your site CSS file http://www.florin-pop.com/work/Simple%20Eats/css/style.css `".navbar"` class has set to `height:70px`, causing dropdown to hide.

Changing `height:70px` to `min-height:70px` will make drop-down appear.

or add below code inside media query `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {}`

`.navbar {
  height: auto; 
  margin: -11px 0 0;
  min-height: 70px;
}`

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't think about this being the problem. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

I just edited the `bs-example-navbar-collapse-1` element css properties of your menu to the following:

```
z-index: 9999;
position:absolute;
background:#FFF;
```

and the menu is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no z-index on your "navbar-collapse collapse in" and also no background.

so add the following

```
position:relative;
z-index: 9999;
background-color: #fff;
```